# SQL Server: getting datewise security count in a query - is there a simpler way to write this?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get date-wise security count that are present in the `priceinfo` table. But the type of security is in a different table (Security master).

Solved the query using the following.

```
with priceinfo as 
(
     select distinct pdate 
     from pricing 
     where pdate >= '20190101'
)
select count(distinct security), pi.pdate 
from pricing pi 
join priceinfo on pricing.pdate = priceinfo.pdate
               and security in (select distinct security 
                                from securitymaster 
                                where pdate = priceinfo.pdate 
                                  and securitytype='BOND' )
group by 
    pi.pdate
order by 
    pi.pdate
```

Is there a simpler way to write this query?

Note: The type of security is available only in security master.
But I need the list of securities that are present in pricing table.

Table: SecurityMaster

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: . . I am baffled how the row count of "1" is calculated.  And the question says "I need the list of securities that are present in pricing table", and I'm clueless on what the results have to do with this.

Comment: The query shortlists only the securities of type 'BOND'. There is only one 'BOND' per day. (Fictional example of course).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select p.pdate, count(*)
from pricing p join
     securitymaster sm
     on p.pdate = sm.pdate and p.security = sm.security
where sm.securitytype = 'Bond'
group by p.pdate
order by p.pdate;
```

Comment: Does not work. Will have to check the reasons. My original query has 'where pdate >= '20190101' in  CTE.